# Debian Bridge Network Connection -- Static IP Addresses

Tags: networking, debian, ip, bridge

I have a PC with 3 Ethernet ports.  I am able to share internet to the other two ports with internet coming in on eth1. I use the following setup on /etc/network/interfaces after aptitude bridge-utils and brctl addbr br0

```
auto lo br0
 iface lo inet loopback

 iface eth1 inet manual
 iface eth2 inet manual
 iface eth3 inet manual

 iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth1 eth2 eth3
```

But now I would like to give everything static IP addresses

```
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth1 eth2 eth3
        address   192.168.10.200
        broadcast 192.168.10.255
        gateway   192.168.10.1
        netmask   255.255.255.0

 iface eth2 inet static
        address   192.168.10.201
        broadcast 192.168.10.255
        gateway   192.168.10.1
        netmask   255.255.255.0

 iface eth3 inet static
        address   192.168.10.202
        broadcast 192.168.10.255
        gateway   192.168.10.1
        netmask   255.255.255.0
```

Can I give eth1 a static IP Address too?  That is where the Ethernet is coming in on.  When Remote Desktop Connecting, I connect to the IP Address of br0.  This configuration does not give me internet access though.  I shouldn't keep the iface eth1,2,3 inet manual lines, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source Code](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-network-interfaces-bridge-eth0-eth1-eth2/)

For the PLC on eth2, (eth1 is the incoming internet connection) make sure it has a static IP address set like

> ```
>   address   10.0.0.3
>   netmask   255.255.255.0
>   gateway   10.0.0.1
> ```

and now I can go live with it on RSLinx ; this still does not give me static IP addresses, but if you set them statically on the device itself, it will still work on this bridge

```
# The loopback network interface 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 
# Ethernet ports setup 
iface eth0 inet manual 
iface eth1 inet manual 
iface eth2 inet manual 
# Network Bridge 
auto br0 
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0 eth1 eth2 
        bridge_maxwait 30
        address 10.0.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255    
        gateway 10.0.0.1 
        # IP of Router /\
```